# Unsafe assignment of an Any value ternary operator

Tags: typescript

I have a doubt related to typescript, and how I can work with union types to make it work. Currently I have this code:

```
   const message: string | string[] = (axiosError as Error).message
    const errorState: string | string[] = Array.isArray(message)
      ? message[0]
      : message
```

The issue I get is in errorStat variable, I know the cause, it is because I am trying to access message[0] and it can be of type string and have no data inside. I know I always got a value inside message.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: `errorState`'s type should only be `string`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wEvlON) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  The error you're seeing should be present, and there should be no unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of places where this will trip up.

The biggest one is that `Array.isArray` and the other answerer's `isArray` type guards only assert whether or not the given type is `any[]`, not any particular `T[]`. If the type guard fails, the type checker knows for sure the type is `string`. But if it passes, the type checker only knows that it's `any[]` and can't figure out anything beyond that.

If, instead, you had this type guard:

```js
function isTypedArray<T>(val: T | T[]): val is T[] {
    return isArray(val);
}
```

Then the type checker will be able to differentiate between `string` and `string[]`.

However, you're then storing it in a variable that you have explicitly typed as `string | string[]`, so when you subsequently try to use `errorMessage`, the type checker will still be confused about the type. Remove the type annotation from `errorMessage`, or change it to just `string`.

Finally, this might not be an issue for your particular use case, but you have a potential bug if `axiosError`'s `message` field is an empty array. The type checker will assert that you have an array, but then when you try to access the value of it at runtime, it will return as `undefined`. That might be acceptable in your situation, but I don't know.

Comment: Great explanation, learned a lot. Thanks moron4hire :)